# Filtering a sampled signal in the frequency domain (FFT)

Tags: matlab, filtering, fft

I capture the input signal of a filter with my oscilloscope and I am trying calculate the signal after filtering.

So I thought what I do is this:

1. convert the signal to the frequency domain with a FFT
2. multiply it with the transfer function of my filter H(w)
3. convert it back to the time domain with IFFT

However it does not work exactly as I expected.

To get a real result out of this, my input to IFFT needs to have conjugate symmetry. So for this to be true my transfer function also needs to have conjugate symmetry.

To achieve this i create a mirrored frequency vector with the second halve negative
(As the result of the transfer function for a negative frequency will be the complex conjugate of the result for the positive frequency).

The resulting output of IFFT is real, but the signal does not match my measurements.
(Imaginary part is actually very small, which I accounted to floating point errors)

However if I just mirror my frequency vector (no negative frequencies), the real part of the signal, after conversion to the time domain, seems to match with my measurement. But in that case I am throwing away the imaginary part (which is
not zero) completely, which doesn't seem right. So I wonder if that is just coincidence.

I have checked the correctness of my transfer function with PSpice, so I know that it is correct.

Can any one tell me what's wrong with my approach?

```
% Input signal is in 'data' 
% Sampling frequency
fs = 25e6;

% Create time vector 
dt = 1/fs;
time = linspace(0,(length(data)-1)*dt,length(data))';

% FFT of sampled input data
data_fft = fft(data);

% Create frequency vector (for even number of samples)
freq = [ 0:length(data)/2 -(length(data)/2-1:-1:1) ] * fs/length(data);
% freq = [ 0:length(data)/2  (length(data)/2-1:-1:1) ] * fs/length(data); 
freq = freq';

% Filter
C1 = 2.2e-6;
C2 = 2.2e-6;
L1 = 0;
rd = 1;
H = pi_filter(2*pi*freq, C1,C2,L1,rd);

% Apply filter
data_fft_filtered = data_fft .* H;

% Convert signal back to time domain
data_filtered = real(ifft(data_fft_filtered)); % Imag part should be zero.
```

pi_filter.m:

```
function gain=pi_filter(w, C1, C2, L1, rd)
    a = -(C1 .* L1 .* w.^2 - 1) ./ ( (C1 .* L1 .* w.^2 - 1).^2 + w.^2 .* rd.^2 .* (C1 - C1.*C2.*L1.*w.^2 + C2).^2 );
    b = ( -1 .* w .* rd .* (C1 - C1 .* C2 .* L1 .* w.^2 + C2)) ./ ( (C1 .* L1 .* w.^2 - 1).^2 + w.^2 .* rd.^2 .* (C1 - C1.*C2.*L1.*w.^2 + C2).^2 );
    gain = complex(a,b);
end
```

**Edit**:

I added the code for the `pi_filter` function as requested in the comments.

I am also adding some screenshots of the input signal.
The actual data is a bit big (50mb), but I can upload it to my Dropbox when I am back at my computer if that would help.

*Blue: Input Signal, Red: Calculated Output Signal, Green: Measured Output signal*

[image] [image]

---

Here is the frequency (magnitude & phase) response of my filter (and the transfer function). The *red* plots are for the parameters used in the sample code above.

[image: Frequency Response]

Comment: @JimMcAdams Yes. The problem in that question seems to be that the frequency response of the filter was not symmetric which mine is.

Comment: Is `H` already in the frequency domain? You never took the `fft` of it. Also be aware that `fft` will be *circular convolution* and also be aware that you made need to center your transfer function, which you can do by using `fftshift`, but if shifting was the issue your output would look correct but be shifted, so I assume that isn't a part of the problem.

Comment: Only with this code, it's very hard to find the problem. Most likely the frequencies in `H` do not correspond with the frequencies in `data_fft`. Could you edit your question to provide the code for `pi_filter` and a diagramm of the desired filter-function (with labeled x- and y-axis)? In addition it would be good to know how your input `data` looks like.

Comment: @megle Could you resolve your problem and if yes - what was it?